# Anyone know an easy way to dump data from MongoDB to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

We have been using MongoDB as our main datastore for a little while but I've been finding it difficult to please our business users with it's lack of relations.

What I'm hoping to do is dump data from Mongo to MySQL to allow these heavy MySQL users the ability to query in a format they are used to.

Does anyone know an elegant way to do this?

I'm hoping to avoid some heavy scripting to get there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Kettle.
Thanks to Adam our engineer he found the solution.

http://kettle.pentaho.com/

They have added a tool to connect to Mongo.
You can then migrate the data to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Read all the data ! Write all the data !

[image: read all the data]

Use your language specific driver for MongoDb and Mysql to fetch all the data from MongoDb and insert into Mysql as per your table schemas. You will need some coding for sure.

Update: You can give a try to this tool :

http://grahamis.com/blog/2010/06/10/squealer-intro/

https://github.com/delitescere/squealer

Comment: I was debating this tactic. Hoping someone had a quicker tool. Ill give it a try!

Comment: try the tool I mentioned , if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Strange question. Do you except arbitrary documents would fit into a RDBMS schema?
You must be dreaming. Try the CSV export...everything else is up to you and your coding skills.

Comment: It's absolutely dependent on how diverse the documents in a collection are. But we have very little variance so it's absolutely achievable.